# Sonar Data in Database is stale, even after deletion of the Projects

Tags: sonarqube

We recently ran out of Oracle Schema space, in the databas we use for Sonar. We deleted some projects, looks like the data is still in the database. WE tried the database cleaner plugin, and also ran a analysis, as running a analysis will remove data related to a removed projects.

However looks like nothing works, the following table takes the junk of data MEASUREMENT_HIGH,Issues and project measures. Please help me a way to purge this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the data is purged per project analysis. So if you have 1000 projects, you will need to run an analysis on each project to purge its past data.

Second, you should customize the purge settings in "General Settings > General > Database Cleaner" to be able to clean as much data as possible. For instance, you can set the "Delete all snapshots after" property to "1" - which means that any analysis older than 1 week will be deleted.